# angular-in-memory-web-api page not found in Angular 4.2.2 CLI web-api

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I'm learning Angular framework (using version 4.2.2) and follow the tutorial Tour of Heroes. In the HTTP section,The tutorial use angular-in-memory-web-api for simulate web api server and I try to use it but it's not working. The message from the browser's console tell me 
  **Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: api/heroes**
  I installed angular-in-memory-web-api by node install npm i angular-in-memory-web-api and this is my code (it's same as the tutorial)[implement in-memory-web-api for api/heroes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Jyu.png) [import module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2UVy.png)   what I miss from the project.

Comment: can i ask about the up right snippet,what is the name of this plugin ?

Comment: it's called InMemoryWebApiModule. In the tutorial tell **"Rather than require a real API server, this example simulates communication with the remote server by adding the InMemoryWebApiModule to the module imports, effectively replacing the Http client's XHR backend service with an in-memory alternative."** you can see the live example here [link] (https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/toh-pt6/eplnkr.html) but I think it is different version because I don't see the package.json in project structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the morning it can run successfully. In the picture(import module), I deleted option {apiBase:""} in InMemoryWebApiModule when imports it and reorder HttpModule and InMemoryWebApiModule.

Answer (score 4):

Check *app/in-memory-data.service.ts*, where **createDb() method returns api endpoints**. Returned object uses ES6 syntax **Object destructuring**, which binds heroes array to a "heroes" field in the object.

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const heroes = [
      { id: 0,  name: 'Zero' },
      { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];
    return {heroes}; // !!!pay attention to this line; it creates api/heroes rest endpoint
  }
}
```

Comment: +1: When I really paid attention to that line I realized that I had written '(heroes)' instead of '{heroes}'. Grrrrr!